# Do I have to run "helm dependency update" every time I change subchart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a repo, where I develop 2 charts. Root chart and a sub-chart.

This is a root chart's `chart.lock`

```
apiVersion: v2
name: tolgee
description: A Helm chart to deploy Tolgee

type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: 1.16.0

dependencies:
  - name: tolgee
    version: 0.1.0
    repository: "file://../tolgee"
    alias: tolgee
```

I am using this chart to actually deploy the thing to my cluster.

While I am working on the project, I am often also changing the sub-chart stored in `../tolgee`. Every time I make a change I need to run `helm dep update`. To get the updated version. I wonder, why the subchart has to be stored as `.tgz`, when it might simply be a link.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one chart depends on another, you can [put an unpacked copy of the dependency](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#managing-dependencies-manually-via-the-charts-directory) into the parent chart's `charts` subdirectory.

This should work with a symlink, too.  So if you're actively working on the subchart but need to install it via the parent, you should be able to

```bash
mkdir charts
cd charts
ln -s ../../tolgee tolgee
```

If you watch carefully what `helm dep up` does, it copies in an archive file `charts/tolgee-0.1.0.tgz`.  While the dependency is in that compressed form, you do in fact need to run `helm dep up` if you make any change.